# Read created at runtime file with java

Tags: java, runtime, filereader

I create and write a file with a java method, then I want to read this file at runtime with another java method.But it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException error.

How could I fix this error?

```
Writer output=null;
File file = new File("train.txt");
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
output.write(trainVal[0] + "\n");
-------------------
and read code

FileInputStream fstreamItem = new FileInputStream("train.tx");
        DataInputStream inItem = new DataInputStream(fstreamItem);
        BufferedReader brItem = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inItem));
        String phraseItem;
        ArrayList<Double> qiF = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while ((phrase = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //doing somethinh here
        }
```

Comment: Double-check the file name. Make sure you close (or at least flush) the output stream before opening the input stream.

Comment: make sure you flush an close your outputstream and try to read the file with the same path you used to create it. If this does't help then you have to show some code.

Comment: To all downvoters: Be very careful with downvoting people with reputation of less then 100; it makes us look hostile.

Comment: I checked the file name It is correct. I closes the stream so the file is created and writen on it.Path is the same I used to create it.

Comment: **train.tx** should be as **train.txt**, check it out.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I know this is a simple question but I could not solve it. I use Eclipse and some refreshing operation is required when I create a file but at runtime I create a file and wanna read it at runtime again ,so it isn't refreshed.May be problem is that.

Comment: eclipse refreshing only affects the view in package explorer ... nothing to do with what your app is performing

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct file name. This includes the path to the file. Also make sure that no one deleted the file between those two functions or renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one of the best and convenient methods to read a file. Go through it instead of using traditional methods.

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        File file = new File("G:/myFile.txt");   //Mention your absolute file path here.
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());
        Scanner scanner=null;
        try
        {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try
        {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine()).append(lineSeparator);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            scanner.close();
        }
        System.out.println(fileContents);   //Displays the file contents directly no need to loop through.
    }
}
```

---

You have made a mistake in giving a proper file extension in your code.

```
FileInputStream fstreamItem = new FileInputStream("train.tx");
```

Should have been

```
FileInputStream fstreamItem = new FileInputStream("train.txt");
```